# extension of $\zeta(s)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n 1/k^s -\int_0^n 1/x^s$

Tags: sequences-and-series, riemann-zeta, bernoulli-numbers

I saw $\zeta(1/2)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n 1/\sqrt k-\int_0^n\ 1/\sqrt x\ dx$
[here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2264494/closed-form-for-sum-k-frac1-sqrtk)
and similarly
$\zeta(s)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n 1/k^s -\int_0^n 1/x^s$ for $0<s<1$.

Rewriting this as $\zeta(s) = \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n 1/k^s -\int_1^n 1/x^s + 1/(s-1)$, I observed it also holds for $s > 1$. (It just follows from $\zeta$'s definition.)
(For example,
$\zeta(1/3) = \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n 1/k^3 -\int_1^n 1/x^{1/3} - 3/2$,
$\zeta(3) = \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n 1/k^3 -\int_1^n 1/x^3 + 1/2$.)
For $s=1$, I can interpret it as $\lim_{s\to 1} \zeta(s)-1/(s-1)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n 1/k -\int_1^n 1/x$, which is the Euler's constant.

Now I wonder is there some interpretation to apply this for $s\leq 0$?
(Some modification is needed because for example
$\zeta(-1) =-1/12 \neq \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n k -\int_1^n x + 1/2  = \lim_{n\to\infty} n/2+1/2 $.
but I could not find any natural modification.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $\Re s>1$. In terms of the Hurwitz zeta function (http://dlmf.nist.gov/25.11)
$$
\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {\frac{1}{{k^s }}}  = \zeta (s) - \sum\limits_{k = n + 1}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{k^s }}}  = \zeta (s) + \frac{1}{{n^s }} - \sum\limits_{k = n}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{k^s }}}  = \zeta (s) + \frac{1}{{n^s }} - \zeta (s,n),
$$
i.e.,
$$
\zeta (s) = \sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {\frac{1}{{k^s }}}  - \frac{1}{{n^s }} + \zeta (s,n).
$$
By analytic continuation, this formula is valid for all complex $s\neq 1$. Now you can use, for example, http://dlmf.nist.gov/25.11.E28 to obtain a more explicit expression that is valid in half-planes of the form $\Re s>-(2N+1)$. You can also use the asymptotic expansion
$$
\zeta (s,n) \sim \frac{{n^{1 - s} }}{{s - 1}} + \frac{1}{{2n^s }} + \sum\limits_{m = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{B_{2m} }}{{(2m)!}}\frac{{\Gamma (s + 2m - 1)}}{{\Gamma (s)}}\frac{1}{{n^{s + 2m - 1} }}} 
$$
as $n\to +\infty$ with fixed $s \neq 1$ (http://dlmf.nist.gov/25.11.E43). Here $B_m$ denotes the Bernoulli numbers. In particular,
$$
\zeta (s) = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to  + \infty } \left( {\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {\frac{1}{{k^s }}}  + \frac{{n^{1 - s} }}{{s - 1}} - \frac{1}{{2n^s }} + \sum\limits_{m = 1}^N {\frac{{B_{2m} }}{{(2m)!}}\frac{{\Gamma (s + 2m - 1)}}{{\Gamma (s)}}\frac{1}{{n^{s + 2m - 1} }}} } \right)
$$
for all $s\neq 1$ and $N$ satisfying $\Re s >  - (2N + 1)$. Note that
$$
\frac{{n^{1 - s} }}{{s - 1}} =  - \int_1^n {\frac{{dx}}{{x^s }}}  + \frac{1}{{s - 1}} .
$$

Comment: The $\zeta(s,n)$ stuff is useless. $\zeta (s) = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to  + \infty } \left( {\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {\frac{1}{{k^s }}}  + \frac{{n^{1 - s} }}{{s - 1}} + \frac{1}{{n^s }} + \sum\limits_{m = 1}^N {\frac{{B_{2m} }}{{(2m)!}}\frac{{\Gamma (s + 2m - 1)}}{{\Gamma (s)}}\frac{1}{{n^{s + 2n - 1} }}} } \right)$ is the answer, the question is how to obtain it.

Comment: @reuns It depends on how you approach the problem. Do you want to solve it from zero, figuring out everything yourself, or you are happy to use known results? In the latter case, it is useful to have the expression in terms of Hurwitz, because afterwards you know that what you need is the asymptotics of this function with respect to its second argument. And that you can find in many places.

Comment: It is not too hard to show that for $\Re(s) > -N-1$ there are some degree $m$ polynomials $f_m(s)$ such that $\zeta(s) = \lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n k^{-s}+ n^{1-s}/(s-1)+\sum_{m=0}^N f_m(s) n^{-s-m}$.