# What is $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(n-1/\sum_{i=n}^\infty i^{-2}\right)$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, asymptotics

Does this sequence converge? If not, what exactly is the behavior of $1/\sum_{i=n}^\infty i^{-2}$ as $n\to\infty$?

My calculations are telling me that the difference is nonnegative and at most $\approx0.5$ for $n\leq 1000000$, but I am not sure how to verify this.

I think it's reasonably easy to see why $1/\sum_{i=n}^\infty i^{-2}$ is $O(n)$, but I am wondering what the correct constant is.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 3):

We have a well-known asymptotic expansion
$$
\sum\limits_{i = n}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{i^2 }}} \sim \frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{{2n^2 }} + \frac{1}{{6n^3 }} -  \cdots 
$$
as $n\to +\infty$ (cf. https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3869508 more generally). Taking reciprocals and expanding the right-hand side, we find
$$
\left( {\sum\limits_{i = n}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{i^2 }}} } \right)^{ - 1} \sim n - \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{{12n}} -  \cdots 
$$
as $n\to +\infty$. Thus,
$$
n - \left( {\sum\limits_{i = n}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{i^2 }}} } \right)^{ - 1}  \sim \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{{12n}} +  \cdots ,
$$
showing that the limit is $\frac{1}{2}$.